# How to encrypt data before save and decript before use

Tags: php, yii

We have an `yii1` site with large number of database queries and for some security point of view, we want to store data in encrypted form and want to decrypt before useage.

I am using beforeSave and afterFind methods but the grid is not working.
Below is my code:

```
public function beforeSave() {
        $this->name = CommonFunctions::encodeString($this->name);
        $this->currency_symbol = CommonFunctions::encodeString($this->currency_symbol);
        $this->is_base_currency = CommonFunctions::encodeString($this->is_base_currency);
        $this->exchange_rate = CommonFunctions::encodeString($this->exchange_rate);
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
    protected function afterFind() {
        $this->name = CommonFunctions::decodeString($this->name);
        $this->currency_symbol = CommonFunctions::decodeString($this->currency_symbol);
        $this->is_base_currency = CommonFunctions::decodeString($this->is_base_currency);
        $this->exchange_rate = CommonFunctions::decodeString($this->exchange_rate);
        parent::afterFind();
    }
```

Comment: Provide the code snippet that you have tried and did not work

Comment: Just implement the encoding/decoding in the data model (-;

Comment: use afterFind and beforeSave in model

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman thank i tried this but fount problem from cgridview filter is not working for me

Comment: @MrugeshThaker i have use afterFind and beforeSave in model but it wont work with gridview widget

Comment: @MrugeshThaker Share your code so i can help you on that.

Comment: @MrugeshThaker i have updated code